# MongoDB Aggregate Two Collection

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, dataset, aggregation

I have two collections. Main - represented by larger mongo document, and second one is smaller. So, both of collections have at least one semanticity similar field - name and title_en. Is it possible to aggregate this two collection into one, using mongoDB aggregation?
I guess in pseudo query it will something like:

```
APPEND to Collection1_DOC (field_name: field_value) from Collection2_DOC
WHERE Collection1_DOC.title_en = Collection2_DOC.Name
```

Is mongo aggregation provide this kind of functionality?

```
{
   "age_rating":"R",
   "age_rating_guide":"17+ (violence & profanity)",
   "average_rating":"82.47",
   "episode_count":26,
   "episode_length":25,
   "poster_image":"https://media.kitsu.io/anime/poster_images/1/original.jpg?1597604210",
   "show_type":"TV",
   "title_en":"Cowboy Bebop",
   "title_ja_jp":"カウボーイビバップ",
   "total_length":650
}
```

```
{
   "End_year":1999,
   "Name":"Cowboy Bebop",
   "Release_season":"Spring",
   "Release_year":1998,
   "Tags":"Action, Adventure, Drama, Sci Fi, Bounty Hunters, Episodic, Noir, Outer Space, Western, Original Work, Drug Use,, Mature Themes,, Nudity,, Violence"
}
```

Comment: Refer this for some relevant information: [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/).

Comment: Thx, i guess i should be reading mongo docs more deeply. For now, i see there's is no way in mongo Aggregation to join two collection without nesting docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out more about aggregation. I want to share pipeline stage, that kinda work for me.

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "info",
      "localField": "Name",
      "foreignField": "title_en",
      "as": "linked_collections"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$linked_collections"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "age_rating": 1,
      "age_rating_guide": 1,
      "average_ratingr": 1,
      "description": 1,
      "episode_count": 1,
      "episode_length": 1,
      "poster_image": 1,
      "show_type": 1,
      "title_en": 1,
      "title_ja_jp": 1,
      "total_length": 1,
      "release_season": "$linked_collections.Release_season",
      "Release_year": "$linked_collections.Release_year",
      "Tags": "$linked_collections.Tags"
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "main_new"
  }
])
```

Unfortunatly, `$out` stage exit with error. But its steel the right way, as i see

```
caused by :: E11000 duplicate key error 
collection: anime_app.tmp.agg_out.c0db80b8-2a40-40cb-84ec-5b8c3c281ca2 
index: _id_ 
dup key: { _id: ObjectId('62da48e463f67a0586394026') }
```

**Update**
This error can be removed by adding this one line of code. It also removed all duplicate. Attaching [answer from MongoDB engineer](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38212?focusedCommentId=2067603&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2067603)

```
{
  "_id":0,
  "age_rating": 1,
}
```